# parameter currentAccessToken is null

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-login

I am integrating the Facebook Login in my app. I am trying to use the `AccessTokenTracker` to listen when the user logs out if he clicks LoginButton. But the app crashes instead if I click the `LoginButton` to logout. Below is the error.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testfblogin, PID: 6687
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter currentAccessToken
        at com.example.testfblogin.MainActivity$onActivityResult$1.onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(AccessTokenTracker.java:110)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

This is how I used the `AccessTokenTracker`:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    object : AccessTokenTracker() {
        override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
            oldAccessToken: AccessToken,
            currentAccessToken: AccessToken
        ) {
            Log.d("APP-TEST", "onCurrentAccessTokenChanged")
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone point to me what I might be doing wrong or missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to make the parameters nullable by putting a `?`

```
object : AccessTokenTracker() {
    override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
        oldAccessToken: AccessToken?,
        currentAccessToken: AccessToken?
    ) {
        Log.d("APP-TEST", "onCurrentAccessTokenChanged")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code segment of accessTokenTracker from the method and paste it outside the method.